# Capture screen content for error parsing

Tags: shell-script, ksh, error-handling

I am a database administrator working with DB2 on AIX. (Please continue to read as this is related more to ksh than DB2, otherwise I would have posted this over on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).) I am attempting to write up ksh scripts for several of our database deployment as well as database maintenance scripts.

I am in the process of putting error handling in our scripts to know whether or not something requires a hard fail or just a warning message, or can be ignored.

With most AIX/ksh related tasks I can check `$? = 0`, but not so with DB2. Unless the database engine fails, I will never get anything but a zero. DB2 will, however, pass back to the console its error/warning/info codes.

Since I know I can get at those codes via the console, I have been trying to capture whatever is on the console for specific command to DB2. Once I have that, I have been sending that output to a function where I use `egrep` and regular expressions to determine if I need to fail (`exit 1`), or succeed (`exit 0`) within my script. I also tend to pipe all output from my script to `tee`, since several of my scripts are long and/or call into multiple other scripts. This way I have a record of the entire "job" that ran both for reference, as well as for troubleshooting my scripts.

Recently, I learned I can `ksh blah.sh 2 > &1 | tee mylog` in order to make sure I capture syntax errors with my script.

I am wondering, what is the best way to handling this kind of error parsing in ksh? I have tried to feed a command to DB2 with the -v option (which is supposed to play the command back to the screen as well as the results of the command) and put that in a variable, but then I actually don't get the command outputted to the screen. Example:

```
RESULT=$(db2 -v drop table blah)
```

I end up having to `cat ${RESULT}` in order to get my screen print for my above pipe to tee and then I still have to pass `RESULT` to my parsing function.

Another thing I have tried is piping the result of my command to a file as well. Example:

```
db2 -v drop table blah | tee myResult
```

This will output to the screen for my high level tee, but now I have an extra file on the file system I have to worry about cleaning up afterwards (though I can `egrep` and `cat` it with no issues). And if my job ever crashes piping to `tee` in script and is itself being piped to `tee` results in some funky behavior (works fine if it succeeds without crashing). This leads me to believe that the double pipe to `tee` is not the best option.

Someone has mentioned to me the `script` command, but I'm not sure if that will help or not?

Any ideas or thoughts? I am assuming I'm not the only one looking to use "screen capture" of specific commands for error parsing while still piping everything to `tee` for an entire job run.

Also I tend to invoke sub shells with my sub scripts instead of calling them as if in the same shell (ie, `ksh blah.sh` vs `. ./blah.sh`). It has seemed to work the best for my scripts. Not sure if that impacts any answers or not.

Any direction based on experience would be appreciated.

Comment: Check `script` but again you have an extra file on your system to worry about.

Comment: I would suggest learning [PERL](http://www.perl.org/) where you can specifically open the file being written and just read from it directly and parse the text, which is what PERL was designed to do.

Comment: @Karlson Perl is not an acronym and should not be all caps. Shell utilities such as awk can read files and parse them as well.

Comment: @jordanm Old force of habit.

Comment: I think Perl is definitely a possible choice. The trick here is I am up against having to write these scripts with a month before "go live" of a piece of software. I am one of the first three DBA's our company has. So I may not have the time to learn Perl before go live. After go live, I may have the time to look into that.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich It would probably take you longer to get the `grep`s right then to learn Perl.  But it's just one man's opinion.

Comment: @Karlson - I am not disagreeing with you. I've read blogs from another DBA about switching from ksh to Perl and the power that brings. Again, the challenge is all the tasks we are facing for go live, plus I'd have to learn Perl, plus teach it to the other DBAs. Like I said, that gets tricky with go live a month away. Ultimately, we may switch to Perl, but I don't think I can do that in a month. Not when I have to help manage 100+ databases....

Comment: @ChrisAldrich I can't assume your learning speed but it might be prudent to make an investment in it up front.  Because implementing scripts in `ksh` with the use of `sed`, `awk`, and `grep`, which for any features you will likely have to use will require you to teach others or rather having them learn it would be a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `tee` or `script`.  Unless you are looking to do the analysis after the fact and offline.

`script` will capture the text output of your shell session and put it into a file `typescript` by default but not necessarily.  Appending or overriding is up to you.

`tee` allows you to dump output of the running command to a file and to allow it to show on the screen as well.

My personal preference would be to have:

```
<command> 2>&1 > <filename>
```

if you need logs of the transactions which you can later analyse.  If you need to analyse them while the `command` is running that would be smarter then simply dumping output into a file:

```
<command> | <script> 2>&1 > <filename>
```

This way you can have the script dump the output selectively or completely into a file and perform other tasks like notification (email, sms, paging, monitoring software notification) without stopping the `command`.

If you want to watch what is happening now within the file, then put the job in the background:

```
<command> 2>&1 > <filename> &
```

and just tail the

```
tail -f <filename>
```

I would assume the output is text and not just message codes.

Comment: Output is text and message codes.

Comment: do if i did db2 -v drop table mytable 2 > &1 > resultsFile &, That will write to the console AND the file?

Comment: No it will write only to the file.  The `tail -f resultsFile` will allow you to see on the console what's being written and take action.

Comment: Actually...I do need to do analysis offline and after-the-fact.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich If all you're looking for is doing the analysis offline then dump the output to a file and analyze it after.

Comment: I actually need it for both. I need it during runtime for analysis of return codes from DB2 (which are printed to the console) in order to know if I need to terminate the job (ie, exit 1) to notify the enterprise job scheduler of an issue. I also need to retain the log of the job (ie, offline) so a DBA can look at the "job log" and try to figure out why there was an issue and correct it. Make sense?

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Then my answer still applies.

Comment: I'll try to give it a shot and see what happens. May take a bit with my other DBA activities I have to take care of....Will post back my results.